# Add selector to SKSpriteNode when pressed

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, sprite-kit, ios10

I need to add a selector or active class of some kind to an SKSpriteNode. So when the user clicks on one of the SKSpriteNodes it tell one to set its Texture to a selected image but also tell any others to be the none selected image.

Below is my function inside of touches began that when the SKSpriteNode is selected it sets the texture to the selected image "1-selected". Say Character 1 was pressed I need to tell Character 2,3,4,x to set image to "1-not-selected".

```
        if Character1.contains(location) {

            Character1.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "1-selected")
            run(ButtonPressed)

        }

        if Character2.contains(location) {

            Character2.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "2-selected")
            run(ButtonPressed)

        }`
```

Comment: you will need some sort of collection of all your sprites (i.e. array) which you will loop through and set the image to none for each sprite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this would be to have all sprites in a set or array, once someone has pressed that button, iterate through this array and run the action you want for each sprite while filtering out the one that was just touched. This also means however that you should take care of adding and removing these sprites from the array once your game is done to not retain this memory.

```
var mySpriteArray = [Sprite1, Sprite2, Sprite3] 

 if Character1.contains(location) {

      Character1.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "1-selected")
      for loopSprite in mySpirteArray{
         if (loopSprite != Character1){
loopSprite.texture = "1-not-selected.png" 
}

        }}
```

You could even extend this so that you do a for loop for each Character and see if it contains your location, so you don't have to do an if statement for each character (i.e. if character1.contains(location), if char2, if char3 etc).

Comment: Thanks i'll give it a try see what happens

Comment: Thats great and works however each character has a different none selected image. So 1 would have 1-non-selected and 2 would have 2-non-selected etc. Any ideas on this?

Comment: Each SKSpriteNode has a name variable, set the name variables on each one when you first initialize them and then pass that as a string when setting the texture. So it would be something like... loopSprite.texture = "\(loopSprite.name)-not-selected.png" . You should try printing this out in the console if you're getting unexpected results